# Sublime Text interface looks blurred

Tags: programming, text-editor, sublime-text

Suddenly my Sublime Text editor started to looks blurred. The screenshot speaks for itself.

No other program fails like this, just Sublime Text.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: sublime text 2 or 3? 32 bit or 64? also are you on a mac? I have seen such complains on their forums from mac users

Comment: 2 and 3 is the same (XFCE or KDE), 32bits. LinuxMint 14 (Ubuntu 12)

Comment: have you tried different themes?

Comment: Yes, I think is something related to some graphical library. But as I told you this started suddenly. No after some upgrade or install a new package.

Comment: This happens when switching themes (sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

This was a very rare case. I just did a clean installation via ppa. And is a good chance to try ST3.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Fixed.

UPDATE: The issue seems to be in some corrupt file inside `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User`

Comment: And here is [how to check](http://www.caniswitchtosublimetext3.com/) whether your requires packages are ST3-ready, also available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Can%20I%20Use).